# QRadioButton only checkable by the program itself

Tags: c++, qt, qradiobutton

This is my first question and I hope I am doing it right.

I am really new to Qt and I am fighting my way through understanding the simple parts. So while I am doing that, i found a problem with the QRadioButtons. I want them to be looking like they're checkable or rather enabled, but I also want them to be only modified by the program itself.
For example the program checks if something is true. Visually shown, it would look something like this

---

( ) Your statement is true

[Button]

( ) Your statement is not true

[] Checkbox

[Button]

---

So if the statement is true, the radioButton1 is checked and enabling the Button, but if it is not true, the radioButton2 is checked and its enabling the checkbox and the other button.

I tried on_radioButton_clicked() with a few methods which dont seem to work.

```
void MainWindow::on_radioButton_clicked()
{
    if (ui->radioButton_2->isChecked()) {
        ui->radioButton->setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

So maybe someone could help me and tell me if there is a simple function on QRadioButton which makes it only changeable by the machine.

Comment: You can disable the "wrong" radio button so the user simply is not able to click there.

Comment: This actually sounds pretty reasonable. I'm ashamed I haven't come up with that. Thanks!